Data correlation with effect of nominal variables
I have a dataset with 4 relevant column with the following information:

the main independent variable (it is a nominal variable, it can take discrete values but hypothetically an infinite number of different values, in my dataset it takes more than 300 values)
the second independent variable (it is a nominal variable, but it can take only 4 different values, let's say a, b, c and d)
the user that carried out the test (it is a nominal variable, it can take a finite number of values depending on the number of people running the test)
the result of the test, expressed as a number in the [0, 10] range

My question, now, is the following. Is there a way to establish if there is any kind of correlation between my data? For example, can I know if, statistically, user1 always obtains higher results than user2? Or that the tests carried out with the second independent variable value set to a always return higher values than when carried out with the second independent variable value set to c?
Hope my problem is clear enough. Btw, feel free to ask me whatever you want if needed.
Thank you in advance!

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly, but wouldn't a regular linear regression fit your purpose ? In a linear regression, the regressors can be nominal, so it should be fine. This could help you answer questions like the one you mentioned.

You've mentioned three quite different questions, and a couple of them seem quite open-ended. It would help if you clarified your exact goal.
